# How to make standalone installation of flash player on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: flash, ubuntu-14.04

I have downloaded flash player tar.gz file for installation. After unpacking it, according to readme file

To execute the standalone player,
          + Double-click, or 
          + Enter in terminal: ./flashplayer

But I don't see any "flashplayer" application in the unpacked directory. Could someone help me?

Comment: did you try looking in the ubuntu software center? It should come pre-packaged there and tested on that OS. According to the following link there are many suggested ways to install but downloading the tar.gz is not listed. http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-adobe-flash-player-ubuntu-14-04/ . That's not to say it won't work but I would definitely try one of the prepackaged methods first

Comment: GNU Shockwave Flash (SWF) player is what I found in the Ubuntu Software Center. The link you gave talks about browser plugins.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that! Do you have a link from where you downloaded flashplayer and I will try to extract myself

Answer (score -1):

You need to unpack the flashplayer with root privileges in `/usr/bin/`. But on Ubuntu 14.04, it does not seem to work...

Comment: And why doesn't it seem to work? I think that's what the OP wanted to know

Comment: Please use answers to post actual answers that work.